# IV Exclusion Restriction

Tags: instrumental-variables

Can an instrument affect the dependent variable through an exogenous variable or do we only need to worry about unmeasured cofounders for the exclusion restriction to hold?

Comment: Yes, worry. See [Spurious Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship).